# AJAX responseText is unreliable

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to send form data to a php script without a redirect.
The problem i have is that the responseText function doesn't seem to work reliably.

NOTE: The PHP script works as intended. And is writing to the database and so on.

AJAX code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#registreer').click(function(){
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "assets/PHP/registreer.php",
            data: $('form').serialize(),
            success: function(jqXHR, textStatus) {alert("Succes" + jqXHR.responseText);},
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus) {alert("Error" + jqXHR.responseText);}
        })
    });
});
```

PHP code:

```
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

// Check connection

if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

if ($passwordPost != $passwordRetypePost) {
    echo "Paswoorden zijn niet hetzelfde!";
} else {
if (!($stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM `Gebruikers` WHERE `Email` = ?"))) {
    echo "Prepare failed: (" . $conn->errno . ") " . $conn->error;
} else {

$stmt->bind_param("s", $emailPost);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($id, $email, $paswoord, $rol);
$stmt->store_result();

if ($stmt->num_rows > 0) {
    echo "Email bestaat al!";
} else {
    $stmt->close();
    $hash = password_hash($passwordPost, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
    if (!($stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO `Gebruikers`(`Email`, `Paswoord`) VALUES (?,'$hash')"))) {
        echo "Prepare failed: (" . $conn->errno . ") " . $conn->error;
    }

    $stmt->bind_param("s", $emailPost);
    $stmt->execute();
    echo 'Gelukt!';
}
}
}

$mysqli->close();
```

So for some reason the only response i can get is:

```
echo "Email bestaat al!";
```

All the other echo's do not seem to be working on my HTML page. No matter what i try.

Any suggestions are welcome!

Comment: if that echo is reached, none of the other echos should have been reached. I don't see the problem.

Comment: In your success callback, the first argument is NOT a jqXHR. are you sure you copied that over correctly?

Answer (score 1):

You receive that message because you're checking if there is already the `$emailPost` in the database and the answer is true. This is why you've received this message.

Have you tried with another email adress ?

Also, in your jQuery callbacks (`success` and `error`) you will always receive "success" things, because you doesn't throw any error, in any case, on the PHP side. 
You should better use something like `throw new Exception('Prepare failed`[...]`')` on every 'echo' or 'die' statement that you have in php, except for the success one where you can correctly use `echo 'Gelukt!';`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!
And yes i've tryed other email adresses. And they get put into my database just fine. But the alert box just has "error" in it. Not the things that are echod.
To me it seems like only 1 echo is actually working.

Comment: haa ! ok ! you would better use "console.log(jqXHR);" in the callbacks instead of using `alert(...)`, you would have more info. 
How do you know that the only response you can get is "Email bestaat al!" if you can only see "error" ?

Comment: Error is part of your error callback for your jquery. Then you have asked for the response text to be printed, but there won't be any response text because the error callback is for when there is a connection problem to the server.

Comment: Just to be clear "Email bestaat al" = "Email already excicts".

And when the email is already present in my database the alert shows: "ErrorEmail betaat al"
But when i get another error for example: "passwords are not the same" It just says "error"

Comment: Ok, thanks to clarify. Are you sure that you've managed to validate the condition `$passwordPost != $passwordRetypePost` when you check with a fake password ? I guess you"re always in the "else" case, and this is why ! Have you ever seen the "Gelukt" message ?

Comment: When i run the PHP page (from the form itself no AJAX) everything echo's and runs as intended.
And i've never seen the "Gelukt" message (means "Succes" FYI)

Comment: Are you sure to see every PHP errors ? Have you tried with that code before yours ?  
```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```